# How to formulate a Batch script if else clause

Tags: batch-processing

I have a simple test to tell me if tomcat8 is running or not. It simply outputs if the service is found or not.

```
net start | find "Tomcat8" > nul 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 echo "Tomcat8 is running"
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 echo "Tomcat8 not running"
```

How could I actually integrate this into a function so I could first test if tomcat8 is running, and if yes - goto end:, and if not - start the service?

eg.

Answer (score 0):

Read `if /?`:

> `%ERRORLEVEL%` will expand into a string representation of the current
>   value of `ERRORLEVEL`, provided that there is not already an
>   environment variable with the name `ERRORLEVEL`, in which case you
>   will get its value instead.  After running a program, the following
>   illustrates `ERRORLEVEL` use:
>
> ```
> goto answer%ERRORLEVEL%
> :answer0
> echo Program had return code 0
> :answer1
> echo Program had return code 1
> ```

Unfortunately, above code snippet seems to be a bit confusing as displays both messages in  case of `errorlevel 0`. Try next (combined with [`find` return codes](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html)):

```
    net start | find "Tomcat8" > nul 2>&1
    goto answer%ERRORLEVEL% 

   :answer0
    echo `find` had return code 0, Tomcat8 is running
    goto :acorp

    :answer1
    echo `find` had return code 1, Tomcat8 not running
    rem code snippet to start the service here
    goto :acorp

    :answer2
    rem dummy/debugging  
    echo `find` had return code 2: invalid switch is given
    pause

    :acorp
```

[Another approach: `IF… ELSE …`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

> Parenthesis can be used to split commands across multiple lines. This
>   enables writing more complex IF… ELSE… commands:
>
> ```
> IF EXIST filename.txt (
>     Echo deleting filename.txt
>     Del filename.txt
>  ) ELSE ( 
>     Echo The file was not found.
>  )
> ```
>
> When using parenthesis the `CMD` shell will expand [read] all the
>   variables at the beginning of the code block and use those values even
>   if the variables value has just been changed. Turning on
>   [DelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) will force the shell to read variables at the
>   start of every line.

```
net start | find "Tomcat8" > nul 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
    echo "Tomcat8 not running"
    rem code snippet to start the service here
) else (
    echo "Tomcat8 is running"
)
```